# WCF REST Services | WebFaultException Handling

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-binding, webhttpbinding

I am testing a WCF REST Service to throw WebFaultException, which contains the error details (created a class ExceptionsView to hold the error details) and the httpStatusCode.BadRequest.

From the client side i created a proxy to access this WCF Service. But i am unable to pass this WebfaultException from the Service to the client.

It returns an error in the Catch{exception ex} statement as "404 Bad Request"

I have used WebHttpBinding as bindingType

Below is the details of the code,

ExceptionsView Class

```
[DataContract]
    public class ExceptionsView
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string Reason { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string DetailedInformation { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string stackTrace { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string Source { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string MethodName { get; set; }
    }
```

Interface :

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GenerateWebFaultException?id={id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[OperationContract]
string GenerateWebFaultException(string id);
```

*

Implementation of this Inteface

```
public string GenerateWebFaultException(string id)
{
    throw new WebFaultException<ExceptionsView>(new ExceptionsView { ErrorId = "123", MethodName = "GenerateWebFaultException", Message = "There was WebFault exception generated", Reason = "WebFaultException" }, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
return "exception";
}
```

Above i am just throwing a WebFaultException, with all the error details.

Now on the client side i am accessing this service using Proxy as below

```
var exampleProxy = ServiceHelper.GetServiceChannel<IExample>();

try
{
    var serviceResult = exampleProxy.GenerateWebFaultException("1");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Here i am unable to get any error details.
    // 400 Bad Request error is returned in response.
   // Can you help me how to get the proper error details from the WCF REST Service to the client
}
```

Let me know if anyone has any solution for this.
I have been scratching my head from last 3 days.
Please help guys..

Image below shows the fiddler result.

[image]

[image: actual error in Business Class (Interface Implementation)]

[image: Error which is displayed on the client side]

[image]

Comment: Did you try `IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults="true"`? Also you need to mark `ExceptionsView` with `[DataContract]` attribute.

Comment: yes i have set the IncludeExceptionDetailsInFaults="true" and also marked ExceptionsView with [DataContract] attribute.

I have edited the post and added the ExceptionsView Class for your reference

Comment: Fine. Next step would be - mark GenerateWebFaultException with `[FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionsView))]`.

Comment: Edited the post. Included the errors on the Service and Client side respectively.|
Tried including the FaultContract attribute as said above.

Comment: So where is `[FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionsView))]`? You should have `[FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionsView))] public string GenerateWebFaultException(string id) ...`

Comment: The screenshot was taken before i implemented your suggestion.
I tried the same but still the same error.